# How to update or add to immutable.js List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm using Redux and Immutable.js in my React-based project (built on [React Boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/)) and I'm looking for an idiomatic way to update or add to an Immutable.js List.

My current setup. State initially looks like this:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  accounts: [],
  activeAccount: null,
  loadedAccounts: [],
});
```

I have an Immutable Record for an `account` object:

```
const account = new Record({
  description: '',
  id: '',
  name: '',
  status: '',
});
```

And my reducer:

```
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS:
      return state
        .set('activeAccount', new account(action.account))
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This works fine - when a `LOAD_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS` action is fired, `activeAccount` is updated to the value of `action.account`.

I can amend this so that every new `LOAD_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS` action pushes the newly-loaded account data to `loadedAccounts` instead:

```
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS:
      const loadedAccount = new account(action.account);
        return state
          .update('loadedAccounts', (loadedAccounts) => loadedAccounts.push(loadedAccount));
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

However, at the moment loading the same account data twice will result in new Records being pushed to my List each time (duplicating data). What I want to do instead is *either* add `action.account` to `loadedAccounts` (as happens now) *or* update the Record in the List if there is a matching ID. I'm looking at similar questions and the lamentable Immutable.js documentation and I can't see how to do this: no syntax I've tried works as I expect here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what do you need here is nested update.
At first, you have to check your list of loadedAccounts whether it has this account or not.
Secondly, you have to change `activeAccount` field.
And, lastly, add (or update) account to `loadedAccounts`.

The caveat here is how you pass `account` property. If you derive it from somewhere and pass around as a `Record`, you can just compare by `===` (or by .equals()), but it seems that it is just a plain javascript object – I'll suppose it later.

In terms of code it would be something like:

```
// we can do it by different ways, it is just one of them
const listWithLoadedAccounts = state.get('loadedAccounts');
const isAccountAlready = Boolean(
  listWithLoadedAccounts.filter(
    account => account.get('id') === action.account.id
  ).size
);

const patchedState = state.set('activeAccount', action.account.id);
return isAccountAlready
  ? patchedState.updateIn(['loadedAccounts'], list => list.map(account => account.get('id') === account.action.id ? new account(action.account) : account))
  : patchedState.updateIn(['loadedAccounts'], list => list.concat(new account(action.account)))
```

It is not the ideal code, something can be deduplicated, but you get the idea – always use deep merge / update if you need to change nested fields or data structures.

You also can set new field directly, like:

```
const oldList = state.get('loadedAccounts');
const newList = oldList.concat(action.account);
const patchedState = state.set('loadedAccounts', newList);
```

But I personally find that it is not that flexible and also not consistent, because it is quite common operation to perform deep merge.

Comment: Thanks - I wrongly assumed that there was a more elegant way to update/add (avoiding your ternary check), but i suppose being explicit like this has its advantages.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this example will help, i am creating a new immutable list and  first performing an update and then adding a new element. i am not passing the object which i want to replace with, but you can also pass your existing object, Also in update method you have access to current item

```js
class Test {
  a = null;
  b = null;
 constructor(a,b){
 this.a=a;
 this.b=b;
 }
}

$("#test").html("");

function logme(item){
  $("#test").append("<br/>"+JSON.stringify(item));
 }
function logmeNewLine(){
  $("#test").append("<br/>");
 }

function listAddUpadte(key){ 
  
     var index= list.get('data').findIndex(listing => {
    return listing.a === key;
  });
  
  logme(' found index (-1 for not found) : ' + index);
  
  if(index >= 0){
    logme("upadte");
    list = list.set("data",list.get("data").update(index,function(item){
    return new Test(key,"go");
    }));
  }else {
    
    logme("add");
    list = list.set("data",list.get("data").push(new Test(key,"go")));
  }

  list.get('data').forEach(item=>{
    logme(item);
  });
}


var list = Immutable.fromJS({
"data":[new Test(6,"abhi"),new Test(4,"raj"),new Test(1,"ajay")]
});

logme("intial data");
list.get('data').forEach(item=>{
  
logme(item);
  
});




logmeNewLine();
logme("testing replace with a =  4 ")
logmeNewLine();
listAddUpadte(4);


logmeNewLine();
logme("testing add with a = 8 ")
logmeNewLine();
listAddUpadte(8);
logmeNewLine();
logmeNewLine();
logmeNewLine();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.7.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since this is the top search result for what is in the title of the question

- https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/push

An example of how to add to a list using immutable.js:

```
let oldList = List([ 1, 2, 3, 4 ])
let newList = oldList.push(5)
```

- https://immutable-js.com/docs/v4.0.0/List/#insert()

> insert()
>
> Returns a new List with value at index with a size 1 more than this List. Values at indices above index are shifted over by 1.
> insert(index: number, value: T): List
> Discussion
>
> This is synonymous with list.splice(index, 0, value).

```
List([ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]).insert(6, 5)
// List [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```